# Making Sphinx format the Markdown code examples in Python docstrings

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to use Sphinx to auto-generate API documentation for a Python library, and I can't make it properly format the example code snippets in the docstrings - they do get indented but lines of the same indentation get concatenated (https://weka-io.github.io/easypy)

I understand that the problem is that the format I'm using to mark the code blocks is Markdown (indent them by 4 spaces) but Sphinx is expecting reStructuredText (`code-block::`)

I've tried googling for a solution and it recommended using [recommonmark](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) - but it seems to be for using `.md` files as the source. I'm using `sphinx-apidoc` to generate the "source" `.rst` files from the Python code - so it's not going to work (unless there is a way to make `sphinx-apidoc` generate `.md` files instead)

So - how do I make Sphinx treat just the Python docstrings as Markdown, leaving the elaborate reStructuredText framework as is for everything else?

Comment: It looks like you just need to add a colon to introduce a literal block (`Example::` instead of `Example:`). See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#literal-blocks (I don't understand what Markdown has to do with this).

Comment: @mzjn Adding that extra colon is the reStructuredText syntax for code block, and just indenting by four columns is the Markdown syntax. This project has been around for a few years before I added the documentation generation, and if possible I prefer to change some Sphinkx configuration to make it accept markdown over modifying all the docstrings in the project to reStructuredText.

Comment: OK... I'll just refactor everything to use reStructuredText...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force sphinx to interpret markdown in python docstrings instead of restructured text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062402/force-sphinx-to-interpret-markdown-in-python-docstrings-instead-of-restructured)