# Force Sphinx to interpret Markdown with MyST in Python docstrings instead of reStructuredText

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, myst

I'm rookie with Sphinx, and I was trying to figure out how to use MyST parser for sphinx to make it work with .autodoc extension.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062402/force-sphinx-to-interpret-markdown-in-python-docstrings-instead-of-restructuredt) thread. I've been trying to convert this code to work with MyST and I failed.

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
import myst_parser

def docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    md  = '\n'.join(lines)
    ast = myst_parser.sphinx_parser.MystParser().parse(md)
    rst = myst_parser.ReStructuredTextRenderer().render(ast)
    lines.clear()
    lines += rst.splitlines()

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', docstring)
```

I don't know what else should I pass to `parse` method. and what to do afterwards (from what I saw myst_parser doesnt have ReStructuredTextRenderer).

Could anyone help me with it?
Thx

Comment: I've just edited the post with more detail

Comment: See open issue in the MyST tracker: https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser/issues/228

Comment: @JohnHennig your code strips out necessary whitespace from the docstring, and doesn't use MyST. You even say "MyST does not yet support Markdown in doc-strings either", which is essentially an answer to this question

Comment: A way to do the above conversion from markdown to rst without losing the whitespace would be great.