# How to create regular text in Sphinx and DocString

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I added Sphinx auto-documenting to my vanilla Django project.

The vanilla Django project has a DocString that I want to keep:

```
"""URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
```

However, Sphinx is trying to process it and gives me these errors:

```
/usr/src/app/porter/urls.py:docstring of porter.urls:5: WARNING: Definition list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
/usr/src/app/porter/urls.py:docstring of porter.urls:7: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.
/usr/src/app/porter/urls.py:docstring of porter.urls:9: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
```

How can I tell Sphinx to just render the text as-is (just a very long description) and don't process it?

Comment: You should be more generous with blank lines. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html?highlight=blank#paragraphs

Comment: you have explanation in error `...ends without a blank line` - so you should add empty lines.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I guess adding lines is the only way to go.  If any of you want to write up something, I'll accept it as the answer.  Thanks again 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of "regular" text, or "plain" or "as is", is poorly defined. Let's think about that… Even when we write something by hand, text is *rendered* onto the page. A text editor processes its input too: It usually renders it in a monospaced font, may apply syntax highlighting, and will either preserve explicit line breaks or soft-wrap paragraphs. Word processors do even more. As does a browser. Without a physical representation, text in its purest form is rather abstract.

Sphinx also processes text, but only performs an intermediate step. It eventually hands over its output to a rendering back-end, such as the browser for HTML documentation, or LaTeX and then ultimately the PDF viewer.

We can tell Sphinx to *not* do any processing by way of the [`raw`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) directive. But the result in this case will not be very appealing. If we copy that doc-string from the question, paste it into a newly created `.html` file, and open that file in the browser, the result will be illegible:

> URL Configuration The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see: httрs://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/ Examples: Function views 1. Add an import: from my_app import views 2. Add a URL to urlpatterns: path('', views.home, name='home') […]

This is where we usually give in and feed the Sphinx what it wants: reStructuredText. That often means adding blank lines before and after blocks, such as [lists](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks).

Personally, I never liked that about reStructuredText. It's supposed to be "minimal mark-up", but whenever I want to introduce a list, like so

```
Here is a list:
* item 1
* item 2
(and maybe even continuing here)
```

it won't understand what I mean and I have to add extra lines, like that:

```
Here is a list:

* item 1
* item 2

(and then the next paragraph)
```

I find this even more annoying when it comes to code examples, which often feel even more intrinsic to a paragraph. Vertical screen space is a precious resource, particularly for doc-strings as they are embedded in the code.

In the past, I went so far as to customize Sphinx's processing, having it add the blank lines automatically just so that I don't have to change my doc-strings. Sphinx provides the [`autodoc-process-docstring`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) event to facilitate that. But ultimately, the parsing and special-casing was too much trouble and now I'm just [using Markdown for the doc-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56062402). Markdown also has some syntax rules, of course. But lists, for example, only need a blank line after the last item, not before the first. So Markdown interferes less with my aesthetic sensibility for… well, "plain-text" doc-strings.

Comment: Thanks for typing this up and informing me that Sphinx has extensions for Markdown. 

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no way of just having the text as-is.

For anyone coming from markdown and not quite used to Sphinx and DocStrings, this is how the extra lines needed to be added in:

```
"""porter URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Examples:

Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
```

Thank you for the confirmation that there's not other, easier way to avoid the warnings.

Comment: This removes the errors but the numbered lists are not treated as lists. For that, you need to add more blank lines. "Function views" is also a paragraph. See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#blank-lines.

Comment: My intent was to not deviate from the original text and just keep the everything as-is. Essentially, hard coding everything. I wasn’t trying to convert the content to a proper Sphinx DocString.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to how you would do it based on your Sphinx DocString experience, and I’ll accept that as the answer.

Comment: If you want to keep the text unformatted, you can use a literal block (https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#literal-blocks). But that is not how I would do it.