# Python Sphinx: How to embed code into a docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, docstring

How can I embed code into a docstring to tell Sphinx to format the code similar as it will be done in Markdown (different background colour, monospaced sans font)? For example to document a code usage example.

```py
""" This is a module documentation

Use this module like this:

   res = aFunction(something, goes, in)
   print(res.avalue)

"""
```

Comment: use f-string like this `string = f"""Example {variable_name}"""`

Comment: @Abbas Sphinx is a documentation rendering engine. F-strings have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[There are a few ways to do it](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#showing-code-examples). I think the most sensible in your case would be [`.. code-block::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block)

```
""" This is a module documentation

Use this module like this:

.. code-block:: python

   res = aFunction(something, goes, in)
   print(res.avalue)

"""
```

Notice the blank line between the directive and the code block - it must be there in order for the block to render properly.

Answer (score 4):

Another way ([see the comment of mzjn on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864260/making-sphinx-format-the-markdown-code-examples-in-python-docstrings)) to get code highlighted is to end with two(!) colons at the line before the code:

```py
""" This is a module documentation

Use this module like this::

   res = aFunction(something, goes, in)
   print(res.avalue)

"""
```

The `::` does the trick.

Comment: It will work, but the syntax highlighting has to be set inside project configuration (see [literal-blocks reference](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#literal-blocks)), or using [`highlight`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-highlight) directive.